# Rank of zero determinant matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If we multiply two $1$-column vectors, by taking transpose of one of them, and get an $n\times n$ matrix called $A$, $\det(A) = 0$ right? Or am I mistaken?

Also I know that rank of $A$ should be less than $n$. But can we say any further info about the rank?

Thanks!

Comment: The rank would be 1 as for $2$x$2$ matrix rank at maximum can be 2 but as det(A) is zero it should be less than 2

Comment: Call the original column vector $v$. Then $A = vv^t$. If there are no zero entries in $v$, then $A$ has not zero columns or rows, but each row is a multiple of the other. Hence $\det A = 0$ and the rank is $1$.

Comment: Thank you @SimonS. Does this hold when two different column vectors are multiplied and rows of these vectors are more than 2?

Comment: What do you think? Now you've seen the pattern for $2 \times 2$, should be relatively straight forward to write down a proof or a counterexample.

Comment: @SimonS I am satisfied with the det being 0 with any number of rows of the column vectors but not sure about the rank..

Comment: Write down a 4 entry column vector, say $v = (a,b,c,d)^t$, and look at $A = vv^t$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, let the vectors be $v$ and $w$. Set
$$A = vw^T$$
Then, for any vector $x$ you have
$$Ax = (vw^T)x = v \underbrace{(w^Tx)}_{\in \mathbb R} = (w^Tx) v.$$
So the range of $A$ is spanned by the single vector $v$, so it is one-dimensional. By the definition of rank we get that the rank of $A$ is one.

As long as $A$ is not $1 \times 1$, this implies that $\det A = 0$.